# wget capture stdout to variable

Tags: shell, wget

I have a shell script that I want to put into a chronjob, and it is supposed to fetch data every day and then write a quick log entry.  I would like the log entries to look something like:

```
2015-12-07 11:16:34: No such file ‘CatchUpPlusActivity_20150801’.
2015-12-07 11:24:20: (14,4 MB/s) - ‘CatchUpPlusActivity_20150801.csv.gz’ saved [52690279]
2015-12-07 11:28:40: File ‘CatchUpPlusActivity_20150801.csv.gz’ already there; not retrieving.
```

My shell script looks like this:

```
sPath="ftp://user:pass@10.10.23.32/public/download/exports/webactivity/PullVODData/"
sFiles="CatchUpPlusActivity_20150801*"

sOut=$(sudo wget ${sPath}${sFiles} -nc)

now="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
echo ${now}: ${sOut}  >> /path/to/logs/catchup_plus.log
```

Where I would like sOut to read the final message from each ftp.  However, I'd be happy for now if it just returned the last line of the whole message.  As it stands sOut is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [progress] output of `wget` goes to stderr, so change your command:

OLD: `sOut=$(sudo wget ${sPath}${sFiles} -nc)`
NEW: `sOut=$(sudo wget ${sPath}${sFiles} -nc 2>&1)`

This will capture *all* lines into a single scalar.  So, if you want to look at individual lines, you'll need to split sOut into an array variable or some such.

**UPDATE:**

To answer your followup question, `2>&1` is a shell thing.

In terms of C-like file descriptor numbers, 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr.  You could have done `wget ... 2>wget.log` and the file `wget.log` would have the same output as the command I gave you.

For any command, "foo" (e.g.) you can divert the output of its stdout with `foo 1>X 2>Y` and X and/or Y can be a file or another *stream descriptor* [the `&Z` syntax].

Note `foo 1>out` is identical to `foo >out` because "1" is the default stream.  The `foo 2>&1 >out` says divert stream 2 to the same place as stream 1, which here is `out`.  Note that `foo >out 2>&1` also works

This also works with appending.  `foo 2>&1 >>out`.

Your sOut syntax said capture the output of stdout [stream 1] for a command.  That is, `sOut=$(foo)`.  When you do `sOut=$(foo 2>&1)` you're telling the *subshell* you spawn to divert it's stderr output to stdout.

The above is just my cursory explanation.  There's a more polished one in the bash manpage.

Comment: what does 2>&1 do?  Is it a wget thing, or is it a shell thing?

Comment: That is an absolutely brilliant explanation, thanks! I wish I could give you more points :)

Comment: @Roman You're welcome!  FYI, normally, I write my scripts in perl.  So, even though I have quite a bit of script writing experience, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to semi-advanced bash.  In addition to the man page, I've found a pretty good online resource: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html The man page just acts like a reference so it's difficult to program from.  The guide page actually provides really good examples to work from.  I was able to provide an answer to another SO bash question, based upon information I found in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

`sOut` is empty because you're not directing the output

```
sOut=$(echo wget ${sPath}${sFiles} -nc)
```

Cheers

Comment: look again.  echo ${now}: ${sOut}  >> /path/to/logs/catchup_plus.log